# Scala: duplicate execution of method in Map values

Tags: java, scala, dictionary, lazy-evaluation, apache-httpclient-4.x

I have implemented a Scala function that executes a HTTP request using HttpClient v4.5.3 from [Apache HttpComponents](https://hc.apache.org/). The idea is to parse the response and check if it is ok (i.e. return code 200). If it is not, retry n times.

When the response is ok, everything works as expected.
I can see from the logger output that the retrying is also executed as expected in case of HTTP errors at first. However, when it has failed n times, it seems to re-start the whole process one more time.

This is the function that executes the request:

```
import org.apache.http.client.methods.{CloseableHttpResponse, HttpPost, HttpUriRequest}
[...]

class SearchQuery {
  [...]
  def executeRequest(retries: Int = 2, delay: Int = 1): Option[SearchResponse] = {
      val request: HttpUriRequest = makeRequest
      val response: CloseableHttpResponse = config.httpClient.execute(request)
      val searchResults: Option[SearchResponse] = parseResponse(response)
      response.close()
      if (searchResults.isEmpty && retries > 0) {
        logger.warn(s"Failed to retrieve response from ${source}. " +
          s"Retrying $retries more time(s) in $delay second(s)...")
        Thread.sleep(delay * 1000)
        executeRequest(retries - 1, delay)
      }
      else searchResults
  }
  [...]
}
```

The method `makeRequest()` generates the HTTP request. `config.httpClient` provides the re-usable `HttpClient` instance.

Apart from the call in the recursion, `executeRequests()` is called as shown below. The idea is to have one or multiple servers (sources), defined by the caller, for which the calls are executed in parallel; they are defined in an `enum` type `Source`. `queryFromfile()` reads the contents of a given file to generate a `SearchQuery` object from which `executeRequest` is then called.

```
val sources: Set[Source] = Set(Source.1)
val file: File = ...
val responses: parallel.ParMap[Source, Option[SearchResponse]] = sources
  .par
  .map(source => (source, SearchQuery.queryFromFile(file, source)))
  .toMap
  .mapValues(query => query.executeRequest())
```

In this example, `executeRequest` is supposed to be called once for each source. One source passes fine, the other one is expected to fail here.

From the logs:

```
14:56:48.656 [scala-execution-context-global-15] WARN  query.SearchQuery - Failed to retrieve response from source1. Retrying 2 more time(s) in 3 second(s)...
14:57:07.136 [scala-execution-context-global-15] WARN  query.SearchQuery - Failed to retrieve response from source1. Retrying 1 more time(s) in 3 second(s)...
14:57:25.538 [ScalaTest-run-running-FileProcessorTest] ERROR process.FileProcessor - Failed to retrieve results for file 'XXX' from sources: source1. Continuing.
14:57:40.933 [scala-execution-context-global-15] WARN  query.SearchQuery - Failed to retrieve response from source1. Retrying 2 more time(s) in 3 second(s)...
14:57:59.214 [scala-execution-context-global-15] WARN  query.SearchQuery - Failed to retrieve response from source1. Retrying 1 more time(s) in 3 second(s)...
```

Using the IntelliJ debugger, the logic also looks as expected as first, ending up in the line `else searchResults` after n tries. However, instead of actually returning the result then, the executor jumps back into the `if` clause, into the recursive call `executeRequest(retries - 1, delay)`.

**Update:**
I figured out this behaviour was caused by subsequent operation on the `responses` val:

```
val emptyResponses = responses.filter(_._2.isEmpty)
if (emptyResponses.nonEmpty)
  logger.error(
    s"Failed to retrieve results for '$fileName' from sources: " +
      s"${emptyResponses.keys.mkString(",")}. Continuing."
  )
```

Here, I check if any of the calls failed and log an error if they did. I do not understand though why this triggers the `executeRequest()` call a second time. Why does it?

Furthermore, the following line does not result in a second call to `executeRequest()` even though it seems conceptually very similar:

```
responses.values
  .filter(response => response.isDefined)
  .map(response => response.get)
```

Comment: Note: using `withFilter` instead of `filter` does not change the behaviour.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why `executeResponse()` is executed another time when accessing the values is that the values of a Scala Map is re-computed every time it is accessed.
`responses` hence needs to be modeled as a tuple `(source, Option[SearchResponse]`:

```
val responses = sources
  .par
  .map(source => (source, SearchQuery.queryFromFile(file, source)))
  .map(pair => (pair._1, pair._2.executeRequest()))
```

This basically eliminates the brevity of `mapValues`, but results in fixed values for the 2nd elements in the tuples.

Comment: Strictly speaking values re-calculated only for `Map`s and `ParMap`s that are result of `mapValues` call. So another possible fix would be to add one more `.toMap` at the end of your `responses` calculation. This would enforce "materialization" of the results so they would not be re-calculated on further accesses.